# How can I remove the last n elements from a list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I would like to delete the last n elements of a list in Prolog and put it in another list say L2. If I knew the exact number of elements to delete say 3, here is the code. But I am stuck with the variable n case. Btw I would like to return an empty string if the length of the list is shorter than n. Thank you.

```
without_last_three([], []).
without_last_three([_], []).
without_last_three([_,_], []).
without_last_three([_,_,_], []).
without_last_three([Head|Tail], [Head|NTail]):-
   without_last_three(Tail, NTail).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general case:

```
without_last_n(L, N, []) :-
    nonvar(L), nonvar(N),
    length(L, M),
    N > M.
without_last_n(L, N, R) :-
    without_last_n_(L, N, R).

without_last_n_(L, N, []) :-
    length(L, N).
without_last_n_([H|T], N, [H|T1]) :-
    without_last_n_(T, N, T1).
```

This satisfies the given requirements, and works with a variety of variable instantiation scenarios. What complicates the solution a bit is the requirement that `without_last_n(L, N, []).` must succeed if `N` is greater than the length of `L`. If this was not a requirement, then the much simpler `without_last_n_/3` would suffice as a solution to the problem.

Testing...

```
| ?- without_last_n([1,2,3,4], 3, R).

R = [1] ? ;

no
| ?- without_last_n([1,2,3,4], N, R).

N = 4
R = [] ? ;

N = 3
R = [1] ? ;

N = 2
R = [1,2] ? ;

N = 1
R = [1,2,3] ? ;

N = 0
R = [1,2,3,4]

(1 ms) yes
| ?- without_last_n([1,2,3,4], N, [1,2]).

N = 2 ? ;

no
| ?- without_last_n(L, 3, [1,2]).

L = [1,2,_,_,_] ? ;

no
| ?- without_last_n(L, 2, R).

L = [_,_]
R = [] ? ;

L = [A,_,_]
R = [A] ? ;

L = [A,B,_,_]
R = [A,B] ? ;

L = [A,B,C,_,_]
R = [A,B,C] ?
...
| ?- without_last_n(L, N, [1,2]).

L = [1,2]
N = 0 ? ;

L = [1,2,_]
N = 1 ? ;

L = [1,2,_,_]
N = 2 ? ;
...
| ?- without_last_n(L, N, R).

L = []
N = 0
R = [] ? ;

L = [_]
N = 1
R = [] ? ;

L = [_,_]
N = 2
R = [] ? ;

L = [_,_,_]
N = 3
R = [] ? ;
...
| ?-
```

A possible flaw here is that `without_last_n([1,2,3,4], N, R).` perhaps could generate solutions *ad infinitum* of `N = 5, R = []`, `N = 6, R = []`, etc. But it doesn't. Left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: There is no reason to enumerate all larger integers ; instead, a clean `instantiation_error` might be a better choice.

Comment: @false - Thanks. The OP's requirement was for `without_last_n(L, N, [])` to succeed for any `N` greater than or equal to the length of `L`. So I wasn't sure how the enumeration should work in that case and struggled with that aspect of "what's the right response".

Comment: Where do you read that requirement? I only read that it should give [] if N is too big.

Comment: @false sorry, I reckon I extrapolated the fuller requirement from the one you just mentioned. The requirements, like many posts on SO, are pretty lightly stated.

Answer (score 5):

```
without_last_n(Old, N, New) :-
    length(Tail, N),
    append(New, Tail, Old).
```

Test run:

```
?- without_last_n([a, b, c, d, e, f], 4, New).
New = [a, b] 

?- without_last_n([a, b, c, d, e, f], 777, New).
false.

?- without_last_n([a, b, c, d, e, f], 0, New).
New = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

*Update.* To succeed with an `[]` when N is bigger than the length of the list, second clause can be added:

```
without_last_n(Old, N, []) :-
    length(Old, L),
    N > L.
```

Comment: This is a nice solution (+1) but doesn't meet the requirement that queries such as `without_last_n([a,b,c], 5, []).` (length greater than first arg) succeed with last arg as `[]`).

Comment: @mbratch I interpreted the phrase "Btw I would like to return an empty string if the length of the list is shorter than n" as that it should fail. It's not clear what "empty string" means in this context.

Comment: Based upon his attempted solution, I interpreted "empty string" as "empty list".

Comment: @mbratch I've updated my answer. Maybe it will help someone in the future.

Comment: Yes I think that meets the user's original requirements and it's nice and tidy.